# Keras: How to load weights from pre-trained classifier into classifier predicting different number of classes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a classification problem that I'm working on with a small dataset (~4000 instances). To boost performance, I would like to train an LSTM on a much larger dataset than mine, save the weights of this network, and load the weights as a sort of "warm start" for the network to be trained on the much smaller dataset, via the `load_model` method in Keras.

However, I'm running into an issue. The larger dataset that I would like to do pre-training on has only 3 classes to predict, and the smaller dataset I would like to use the weights for has 5 classes. Obviously, when I load the weights into the architecture for the smaller dataset, I'll receive an error when trying to fit this model. I can't set the `input_shape` or `output_shape` of any of the layers to the pre-trained network, at least not the way I've tried. That is, if I do the following:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('path/to/model_weights.h5')
print model.layers
# [<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM at 0x1197d10d0>,
# <keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x11d9d6f50>,
# <keras.layers.core.Activation at 0x120beb810>]
model.layers[1].output_shape = (None, 5) # Trying to set different output dimension here
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4f1957074c0c> in <module>()
----> 1 model.layers[1].output_shape = (None, 5)

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I get the `AttributeError` listed above. Is there another way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why won't you just add another Dense layer on top with the right amount of classes? then train the two layers together.